# Wordpress Dashboard issues

Tags: wordpress, macos, firefox, dashboard

In Firefox 64.0.2, Mac OSX 10.13.6, Wordpress Dashboard issues. No Markup menu appears above a post's content area.  I don't like to use Chrome, but am forced to do that today so that the Wordpress Dashboard works properly. Otherwise I can't add a link or make anything bold or italic without manually typing in the html in Firefox.

Comment: Please show the HTML

Answer (score 0):

What version of word-press are you using (in the admin on the dashboard tab in the at a glance section)? Are there any Java Script errors in your console (right click and inspect element the click console tab)?
I tested version 4.9.9 with Fire Fox and it seams to be working for me...
Make sure your in the Text tab when editing.